# How To Query an array of JSONB

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have table (orders) with `jsonb[]` column named `steps` in Postgres db.

I need create SQL query to select records where Step1 and Step2 and Step3 has *success status*

```
[
 {
  "step_name"=>"Step1",
  "status"=>"success",
  "timestamp"=>1636120240
  },
 {
  "step_name"=>"Step2",
  "status"=>"success",
  "timestamp"=>1636120275
 },
 {
  "step_name"=>"Step3",
  "status"=>"success",
  "timestamp"=>1636120279
 },
 {
  "step_name"=>"Step4", 
  "timestamp"=>1636120236
  "status"=>"success"
  }
]
```

table structure
id | name | steps (jsonb)

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Normalize' `steps` into a list of JSON items and check whether every one of them has `"status":"success"`. BTW your example is not valid JSON. All `=>` need to be replaced with `:` and a comma is missing.

```sql
select id, name from orders
where
(
 select bool_and(j->>'status' = 'success') 
 from jsonb_array_elements(steps) j
 where j->>'step_name' in ('Step1','Step2','Step3') -- if not all steps but only these are needed
);
```

Comment: Can we use this query with CASE...THEN... END clause ? 
For ex. if Step1','Step2','Step3' is success order has "Devilered" status

Comment: Yes, for sure. There are several options. I am trying however to make queries as declarative as possible and avoid hard-coding of details. But this is a matter of personal taste actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON value contain operation for check condition exist or not

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=06a6573ce3c52af4b82c18b5d7a21812)

```sql
select
  *
from
  test
where
  steps @> '[{"step_name":"Step1","status":"success"},{"step_name":"Step2","status":"success"},{"step_name":"Step3","status":"success"}]'
```

Comment: What if the number of steps is unknown upfront?